# Motion equation given the following function, is this a potential function?

Tags: calculus, physics, vector-fields

I'm a bit rusty in this stuff.
I'm trying to design an energy function that would allow me to derive a motion equation.

I'm considering the vector field

$$
F(x,y,z) = k\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},0 \right)^T
$$

($k$ positive constant). I've checked the condition

$$
curl(F) = 0
$$
for all $x,y,z$, and indeed I get 0. However the components aren't differentiable in $(x,y) = 0$ which basically confuses me a little bit.

Is there a slightly modification I could do maybe to get something more sensible? But I'm not sure if this matters though.

The other question is I have the potential function

$$
U(x,y,z) = k \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
$$

and I clearly have

$$
\nabla U = F
$$

How do I derive the motion equation? My intuition is that since

$$
F = ma = m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}
$$

I have to relate both $U$ and the motion equation, is there some Euler lagrange equation (in general not for this specific case) I should use?

Comment: You are in 3D, so the motion equation is $-\text{grad}(U)=\underline{F}=m\underline{a}=m\underline{\ddot{r}}$: $$k \,\text{grad}(r)+m\underline{\ddot{r}}=0$$.

Comment: Your vector field is undefined at the origin, so it shouldn’t be a surprise that none of the derivatives exist there, either.

Comment: It's not a surprise and I was indeed puzzled, but the field is conservative anyway right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the cylindric coordinates $\phi$, $r$, $z$, where 
$$[x,y,z]= [r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi),z].$$
We then have for the kinetic energy
$$
T = \frac{m}{2}\left(r^2\dot{\phi}^2 + \dot{r}^2 + \dot{z}^2\right)
$$
and for the potential simply
$$
U = k r.
$$
Now apply Euler-Lagrange:
$$
L = T - V
$$
and
$$
d_t\partial_{\dot{q}}L = \partial_q L$$
where $q\in \lbrace\phi,r,z\rbrace$. This will give you your equations of motion:
$$
\ddot{z} = 0,
$$
conservation of momentum in $z$-direction,
$$
r\ddot{\phi} + 2\dot{r}\dot{\phi} = 0 = \dot{J},
$$
conservation of angluar momentum $J = mr^2\dot{\phi}$, and finally
$$
m\ddot{r} = mr\dot{\phi}^2-k = \frac{J^2}{mr^3} - k.
$$
$J$ in the last equation is constant because of the conservation of angluar momentum. So now you are left with a decoupled equation for $r$.

Comment: But is my function $U$ a valid potential?

Comment: Sure, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: Thank you, If I post a more complicated question do you think you can give me some insight on that one?

Comment: @user8469759 feel free to post whatever. If i can't answer, maybe someone else may do so ;).

Comment: Posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903927/is-the-the-derivation-of-the-following-motion-equation-correct. If you have time please have a look.